# WSO2 Identity Server upgrade

Tags: wso2, migration, upgrade, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 4.5.0 and i would like to upgrade to the last version (4.6.0 on 31/12/2013)

Wso2is data are stored in the default Apache-DS embeded with WSO2 Identity Server

What is the best way to upgrade and keep the data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running WSO2 IS 4.5.0 with default configurations..  it means with default database (H2) and default user store (ApacheDS).  Then you can migrate data by performing following two operations.

1. Copy 450 H2 database in to 460.  You can copy 450 /repository/database directory in to 460 and replace.
2. Copy 450 ApacheDS data in to 460. You can copy 450 /repository/data directory in to 460 and replace.

Please not,  in production,  It is not recommended to use default database and user store. Normally it is used database such as MySQL, MSSQL Oracle and so on.. Also OpenLDAP, AD, ApacheDS (separate instance) and so on.  Therefore when migration is happened, you can start new server by pointing same database and user store that are used in previous version.

Comment: And one additional tag("RegistryKeyStore") has been added to carbon.xml when moving 4.5.0 to 4.6.0

Comment: <RegistryKeyStore>
            <!-- Keystore file location-->
            <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/wso2carbon_.jks</Location>
            <!-- Keystore type (JKS/PKCS12 etc.)-->
            <Type>JKS</Type>
            <!-- Keystore password-->
            <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            <!-- Private Key alias-->
            <KeyAlias>wso2carbon</KeyAlias>
            <!-- Private Key password-->
            <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
        </RegistryKeyStore>

Comment: Add above "RegistryKeyStore" under "Security" element (As a sibling of "KeyStore" element)